# How to get triggered on scrolling inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?

Tags: angular, events, scroll, virtualscroll

I'm using virtual scroll with Angular 7. I create a `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` and I would add a listener to every scroll event. I mean I would like to be notified on scrolling inside that viewport.

I tried to inject `scrollDispatcher` in my component, but I see that `scrolled()` is triggered on scrolling on the whole component, then I figure out that it is bind to the component instead of just to `CdkVirtualScrollViewport`.

Here is my code:

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) virtualScroll: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

items: Array<any>;

constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
this.items = [];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    this.items.push(i);
  }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
  .subscribe(event => {
    console.log('scrolled');
  });
}
```

As you can see `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` is a child element inside my component:

```
<div class="header">
  {{header}}
</div>

<div class="container">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="4" class='example-viewport'>
    <li *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class='example-item' >{{item}}</li>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  {{footer}}
</div>
```

Here is the full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-scroll-dispatcher

Maybe I could use `register()` method of `scrollDispatcher`... but I should pass a `CdkScrollable` to it, instead mine is a `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` element.

Then, how can I listen only to my virtual scroll viewport scrolling events?

Answer (score 6):

The way for listening to scroll events within `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` is using `elementScrolled()` method:

```
this.virtualScroll.elementScrolled()
  .subscribe(event => {
    console.log('scrolled');
  });
```

So there is no need to inject `scrollDispatcher` and register any element...